# Связь таблиц PostgreSQL на стадии создания

Tags: postgresql

Делаю БД на PostgreSQL. Вне контекста прочих языков программирования.

В структуре присутствуют таблицы: "Студент", "Группа".

Такой вопрос: Как в таблице "Группа" сохранить ФИО/ID каждого студента, который входит в группу без дублирования группы?

Иными словами:
Нужно, чтобы была запись
Группа "Программирование"| Студенты "Пупкин В.И., Пушкин А.С., ..." или их айди в таблице "Студент";

вместо записи

Группа "Программирование"| Студенты "Пупкин В.И."

Группа "Программирование"| Студенты "Пушкин А.С."

...

Comment: А в чем проблема дублирования id группы?

Comment: Далее группы будут использованы для указания дисциплин, которые изучаются каждой группой. Если, условно, в группах по 30 человек и, возможно, меньше , а групп 5-6, это будет затруднительно искать где начинается следующая группа

Comment: У студента должен быть ид группы. Выборка должна быть с джойном таблиц. Записывать в таблицу с группой ид студента - как то не правильно

Comment: А как быть, если студентов могут присоединять больше чем в одну группу?

Comment: Если студент может быть в нескольких группах, сделайте промежуточную таблицу связку ид_студента, ид_группы и через нее джйоните и группируйте. А [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query) показано, как выборку полей можно уложить в строку, что бы получить список фио